# Spring boot unauthorized response with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have spring boot + spring security application and I discovered strange behavior. When I send request with wrong authorization (basic), I receive normal error message in body:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-01-15T11:59:31.837+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Bad credentials",
    "path": "/karbonator/api/v1/wallet"
}
```

But if I put **X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest** in header - I will receive only status 401 **without body**.

Is it normal? How can I fix it and receive error message in body with header **XMLHttpRequest**?

Spring boot version is **1.5.9.RELEASE**

I do not use any custom header filters. Security configuration is simple:

**SecurityBeanConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityBeanConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                User user = userRepository.get(s);
                if (Objects.nonNull(user)) {
                    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                            user.getUsername(),
                            user.getPassword(),
                            true,
                            true,
                            true,
                            true,
                            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(""));
                } else {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find the user " + s);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().csrf().disable()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

All project available here: https://github.com/rublin/XMLHttpRequest

P.S. It looks like the [Spring Security issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4968)

Comment: if you can share code snippet of how you're defining the header.

Comment: added code samples and link to the repository

Comment: Are you sure about using "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" and not "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest"? Hope it is fixed with = sign

Comment: Of course i send valid header: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rublin/XMLHttpRequest/master/with_header.png